# How to add class to chosen elements in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've got an array of comments, and want a part of them to be hidden, if `hidden` param is `true`, before a user clicks on a "load more" button.

But it doesn't work properly, instead it adds `hidden` class to all comments but the last one.

```js
async function comments(...arr) {
  let i = 0;
  const container = document.querySelector('.comments')

  function setHidden(h) {
    if (h === true) {
      $('.comment').addClass('hidden')
    } else {
      $('.comment').removeClass('hidden')
    }
  }

  for (let i of arr) {
    await setHidden(i.hidden)
    $(container).append(`<div class="comment">${i.comment}</div>`)
  }
}

comments({
  comment: 'hi'
}, {
  hidden: true,
  comment: 'how are you'
}, {
  hidden: true,
  comment: 'where are you from?'
});
```

Comment: You don't need to use `async/await`. `setHidden` doesn't return a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from Rory's answer, if you did want to use jQuery throughout (you're mixing and matching with vanilla JS at the moment) you can.

```js
function comments(...arr) {
  
  const container = $('.comments');

  $.each(arr, (i, obj) => {
    const comment = $(`<div class="comment">div>`);
    if (obj.hidden) comment.addClass('hidden');
    comment.text(obj.comment);
    $(container).append(comment);
  });

}

comments({
  comment: 'hi'
}, {
  hidden: true,
  comment: 'how are you'
}, {
  hidden: true,
  comment: 'where are you from?'
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comments"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as mentioned by @Andy in the comments, you don't need async/await here, as `setHidden()` doesn't return a promise.

The reason your current logic doesn't work for the last comment is because you haven't added it to the DOM at the point you invoke the `setHidden()` function in the final loop iteration.

Also note that the logic is flawed because all `.comment` elements will be hidden based on the state of the ***last*** `i.hidden` value. You should instead set the `.hidden` class on the `.comment` you create within the `for` loop, not all of them at once.

It's also a simple exercise to do this without jQuery; no point adding a library for a single line of code.

```js
function comments(...arr) {
  const container = document.querySelector('.comments');

  for (let comment of arr) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('comment')
    comment.hidden && div.classList.add('hidden');
    div.textContent = comment.comment;
    container.appendChild(div);
  }
}

comments({
  comment: 'hi'
}, {
  hidden: true,
  comment: 'how are you'
}, {
  hidden: true,
  comment: 'where are you from?'
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Comments:</h3>
<div class="comments"></div>
```